# Какими частями речи "точно" и "предположительно" являются в зависимости от типа предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Как ставить знаки препинания в зависимости от типа предложения (вопросительного, утвердительного, неуверенности) ?

1. Это точно он !/? (!?);   Точно, это он!;   Точно это он?;   Это он, точно!/? (!?).

Когда слово "предположительно" вводное, а когда наречие? Как отличить наречие (то же, что «опираясь на предположения, на основании предположений, догадок») от вводного слова (то же, что «вероятно, возможно, скорее всего») ? По-моему, это почти одно и тоже. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_625

2. Цивилизация  зародилась предположительно в 11-м веке до н.э.
3. На границе перехвачена крупная партия наркотиков, предположительно кокаина.
4. Вертолет упал  предположительно в районе  сел Чабанмахи и  Карамахи.
5. Поезд ожидается предположительно в 23:45.
6. Смерть наступила предположительно между 12 и часом ночи.

Comment: Уважаемый Угрюм Веселов! Вы задаете актуальные вопросы, они действительно решаются неоднозначно, их можно обсуждать. Но вот что интересно: ваши вопросы однотипны, меняются только конкретные слова, а суть одна и та же. При этом вы не принимаете ответы, редко их комментируете, а потом спрашиваете фактически об одном и том же. Складывается впечатление, что вы ответы или не читаете вовсе, или читаете очень невнимательно.

Comment: Уважаемая Vera! Я думаю, Вы глубоко ошибаетесь. Я не считаю свои вопросы однотипными (у меня даже и в мыслях не было, пока Вы не написали об этом). Просто я читаю на досуге словарь вводных слов и справочник Розенталя,   нахожу конкретные  примеры. Потом захожу на "Грамоту" или другой какой-то подобный сайт, а там написано немного по-другому или совсем по-другому, или полная противоположность. Или просто не могу понять: похожие примеры, а запятые расставлены по-разному. Я все ответы перечитываю помногу раз, всегда ставлю плюсик и галочку. Зачем комментировать, если ответы меня устраивают ?

Comment: Когда нет обратной связи, то кажется, что мы плохо объясняем. Знаете, это как задачи в математике. Объяснили принцип решения, а потом решают задачи по теме. Если понятен принцип, то  третий-четвертый пример можно решить самостоятельно по аналогии. И тогда вы уже не спрашиваете, а высказываете свое мнение, например: я считаю, что в этом учебнике правильно, а в том нет. А мы уже обсуждаем вашу точку зрения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это тема связана с определение синтаксической роли наречия: обстоятельство или вводное слово.

Семантические значения  для слов ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНО и ТОЧНО в обоих случаях близки, поэтому различение функций делается по структуре предложения, по интонации, по наличию логического ударения.

1) Это точно Он !  ТОчно это он?  Нет пауз.

Это Он, тОчно! ТОчно, это Он!  Паузы, расположение вводного слова в начале или конце предложения.

2) Цивилизация зародилась (предположительно в 11-м веке до н.э).

На границе перехвачена крупная партия наркотиков, предположительно кокаина.

Вертолет упал (предположительно в районе сел Чабанмахи и Карамахи).

Поезд ожидается (предположительно в 23:45).

Смерть наступила предположительно между 12 и часом ночи.

В трех предложениях прослеживается тесная связь "предположительно" с последующим обстоятельством. В одном предложении "предположительно" переходит в присоединительный союз с модальным значением.

Answer (score 4):

1 и 3. *Это точно он!/? Точно [ли] это он?* Простые предложения

2 и 4. *Точно, это он! Это он, точно!* (Ну, одно и то же, просто слова переставили). Сложносочиненные или близкие к ним.

Мне что-то трудно представить "предположительно" в роли вводного.

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_625

Comment: 1. Употребляется в функции вводного в модальном значении «неуверенность, предположение»: Так нежно и ярко выло его сияние, что, будучи, предположительно, свободным от мира, я пожелал бы бессмертия (А.Грин); По одной стороне - приемная, кабинет доктора, дальше, предположительно, столовая и гостиная (В.Набоков); Назначенное, предположительно, на срок месяца три спустя открытие нового Университета, должно было стать самым торжественным и широко освещаемым действом (В.Набоков). "Словарь вводных слов" Остроумова О.А., Фрамполь О.Д.

Comment: 2. Редко невводное, употребляется в функции обстоятельства образа действия, произносится тоном уверенности, убежденности, без паузы перед следующим словом, не обособляется: У каждой эпохи предположительно существует своя собственная тональность, и поэзия фиксирует эту тональность первой (И.Бродский); Никто этого делать не стал, - возможно, оттого, что каждый склонен к определенной учтивости при обращении со старым и предположительно очень пьяным господином (В.Набоков); Цены на картофель предположительно вырастут на 10 рублей. "Словарь вводных слов" Остроумова О.А., Фрамполь О.Д.

Comment: Хотя бывает "трудно представить  ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНО  в роли вводного", но словарь "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" утверждает,  что это возможно, например: "Книгу эту я я буду писать, предположительно, всю жизнь ((В. Войнович).